# Is there a way to convert unknow file type to human readable format?

Tags: file, type-conversion, data-conversion, human-readable

I believe the files were incorrectly converted when I used "recoverit" recovery software. I have included a screen shot to show how the file looks when opened in "VS Code".[image: File appearance in VS Code]